Añadir template tag en plugin de wordpress
Disculpad si cometo algún error en la redacción. Trabajo con un plugin que de reservas que me configura unas plantillas para notificar al usuario que ha reservado. Estas plantillas se configuran con unos tags (comparto a continuación). Justo el campo que necesito no aparece como tag y si no me equivoco es una variable más de la BBDD de donde sale las demás. La variable sería "Seats" y mostraría la silla y la mesa que el usuario ha escogido.
Estoy intentando buscar en el código del plugin (en el FTP) pero no encuentro donde insertar esta nueva tag.
Cualquier ayuda será agradecida y bien recibida.
Un saludo
<div class="wpc-tab" data-id="notification-reservation-settings">
  <div class="wpc-label-item wpc-email-tag">
    <div class="wpc-label">
      <label for="wpc_admin_email_address">Template Tags</label>
      <p class="wpc-desc">
        Use the following tags to automatically add reservation information to the emails
      </p>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{user_email}</strong> Email of the user who made the booking
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{user_name}</strong> * Name of the user who made the booking
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{party}</strong> * Number of people booked
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{date}</strong> * Date and time of the booking
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{phone}</strong> Phone number if supplied with the request
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{message}</strong> Message added to the request
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{site_name}</strong> The name of this website
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{site_link}</strong> A link to this website
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{current_time}</strong> Current date and time
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{invoice_no}</strong> Invoice no. of reservation
      </div>
      <div class="wpc-template-tags-box">
        <strong>{branch_name}</strong> Branch Name
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`



Ya intentaste hablar con los del plugin o leer la documentación técnica del mismo? Para ayudarte se tendría que estudiar ese Plugin y como entenderás eso nadie lo hará. Te recomiendo ver y leer el [tour] y [ask]

Falta información para poder entender tu problema, por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour]

Indícanos que has intentado y como, o los errores que te da

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

1/ agrega nombre del plugin o nombre de la carpeta del plugin, por lo general los plugins "templateables" incluyen una carpeta templates con archivos que podes copiar y modificar en el child theme. si es un agregado de woocommerce por lo general van en la carpeta woocommerce/{algo}/ el {algo} puede ser el nombre del template o una carpeta con el nombre del plugin y dentro el nombre del template.

2/ En plugins por lo general se usa wc_get_template (woocommerce) o get_template_part (wordpress core) para localizar, cargar e insertar un template si estas analizando el plugin buscar esas funciones te da una pista de cómo y dónde busca el plugin los templates.
